# Oc command to output service name which has 100%

Tags: bash, shell, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I have a openshift command

```
oc get route ABCD
```

It gives information route and services attached to it. We can have multiple services attached to it and define % of traffic to each of the services

Question is - when i do

```
oc get route ABCD | awk '{print $6}'
```

i get below output

```
ABCD-a(0%), ABCD-b(100%)
```

Now i want the output that just have 100% in it ex:

```
ABCD-b
```

I tried to use cut command but did not get it

I understand it is just a string manipulation but i have hard time.

Comment: I tried formatting the question for you, please check them. If you want to include some code either prepend the code with 4 spaces or put the code inside \` \` backticks.

Comment: your question is unclear, please provide sample input, and sample output.

Answer (score 1):

I did this - it worked fine i guess >>

```
oc get route ABCD | awk '{print $6}' | tr ',' '\n' | grep 100% | cut -d '(' -f 1
```

Let me know if there is a better way

Comment: No, that looks fine. Probably in shell I would do a similar thing. Probably I think I would substitute space for newline `tr ' ' '\n'`, with `tr ',' '\n'` you probably end with a leading space in front of ABCD.